# Count even numbers from function output in R

Tags: r, fibonacci

I am working through the [Euler Problems](https://projecteuler.net/), and the problem is to sum the even terms in a Fibonacci sequence up to the length where the last term is < 4e6.  I got it eventually but the following method of counting the even numbers did not work, and I am curious as to why.

First, this method of counting even numbers from a sequence works:

```
numbers <- 1:32
N <- length(numbers)
total <- rep(0,N)
for (i in numbers){
  if(i %% 2 == 0) total[i] <-i
  }   
sum(total) #272
```

Then, this Fibb sequence works:

```
Fibb<-function(x){
  y <- 1:x
  y[1] = 1
  y[2] = 2
  for (i in 3:x){
    y[i] <- y[i-2] + y[i-1]
  }
  return(y)   
}
```

but the same sum function I used on the first sequence doesn't work:

```
numbers <- as.integer(Fibb(32)) # 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21...
N <- length(numbers)
total <- rep(0,N)
for (i in numbers){
  if(i %% 2 == 0) total[i] <-i
  }  
sum(total) #NA
```

The `total` of the third chunk is a large numeric, mostly composed of NAs.

EDIT: What I'd like to know is why the loop in the first block of code runs correctly and not that in the third; I copied and pasted likes 6-7, from the first chunk to the third, the only difference is the "numbers" sequence.

Has anyone encountered a problem like this?
Thanks!

Comment: For the sum, take advantage of indexing and vectorization to avoid a loop. For example: `total = cumsum(numbers[numbers %% 2 == 0])`.

Comment: Yeah eventually i went with
    flag <- numbers %% 2 ==0 
    qq <- sum(numbers[flag])

But in the meantime I'm curious why the two loops give different results with syntax identical in all but one line.

Comment: Look at the values of the first version of `numbers` and the second version of `numbers` and note that it's the *values* of `numbers` and not the *index* of `numbers` that you're using as your loop index. Also look at the length and values of `total` after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using elements of `numbers` as your index into `total`.

See how you have `for (i in numbers)`. So (for example) when considering the Fibbonaci number 2584 in `numbers`, you are setting `total[2584] <- 1`.

Your eventual `total` vector is 3524578 elements long (!!) when it only needs to be 32 long. All the other elements that you don't store a result in are set to `NA`, and the `sum` of `NA` is `NA`.

Separate out your Fibonacci number (which can be arbitrarily large) from your index into `total` (which only goes up to 32). To make the index, you can use `seq_along(numbers)` which is essentially `1:length(numbers)`. Then use `numbers[i]` to get that Fibonacci number.

```
for (i in seq_along(numbers)) {
    if(numbers[i] %% 2 == 0) total[i] <- 1
}
```

Comment: Hi mathematicalcoffee,